# AngularJS - ui-bootstrap pagination error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im getting an error with ui-bootstrap pagination **Unknown provider: startFromFilterProvider**

Here is my controller code:

```
function observedCars($scope, $http, API, CarDetailService, $state) {
  $http.get( API + '/car/?observed=true&offset=0&page_size=20' ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.observed = data;
  });

  $scope.pageSize = 5;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;

  $scope.selectCar = function(carId) {
    CarDetailService.setCar(carId);
    $state.go('taskDetails');
  };
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="observedCars">
  <div ng-repeat="obv in observed['Observed CARs'] | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize" class="myCar">
    <div class="carId">{{ obv['Display Name'] }}</div>
    <div class="title">{{ obv['Project Title'] }}</div>
    <div class="status"> {{obv.Status}} </div>
    <h4><u>Current Approver</u></h4>
    <div class="currApp dont-break-out">{{obv['Current Approver']}}</div>
    <h4><u>Amount</u></h4>
    <div class="modified">${{obv.Amount | number:2}}</div>
    <div class="carBtnWrap">
      <div class="viewCar"><a ng-click="selectCar(obv['CAR ID'])">View Details</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul uib-pagination total-items="observed['Observed CARs'].length" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="pageSize"></ul>

</div>
```

Also I should mention that it does show the right amount of button numbers in "uib-pagination" button section. So the proper amount of pages loads just not data cause of the error.

How can I fix this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you didn't declare or define the startFrom filter. There is an exemple found here : [AngularJS with AngularUI Bootsrap pagination directive doesn't hide results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460926/angularjs-with-angularui-bootsrap-pagination-directive-doesnt-hide-results)

```
app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {



        if (input === undefined || input === null || input.length === 0
         || start === undefined || start === null || start.length === 0 || start === NaN) return [];
        start = +start; //parse to int

        try {
            var result = input.slice(start);
            return result;

        } catch (e) {

        //    alert(input);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: thumbs up! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `startFrom` filter in the following expression: `<div ng-repeat="obv in observed['Observed CARs'] | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize" class="myCar">`

You can probably copy the implementation for `startFrom` from your example, or you forgot to embed it. A common implementation is as follows:

```
module.filter('startFrom', function () {
  return function (input, skipCount) {
    if (!input) return input;
    return input.slice(skipCount);
  };
});
```